# Saving JavaScript `console.log` to global variable or file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access `console.log` data programmatically and so I need to implement a `console.log` which stores its data in a global variable or file.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You want a [logger](http://www.songho.ca/misc/logger/logger.html) kind of stuff? Also have a look @ [Log Level - Minimal lightweight simple logging for JavaScript. loglevel replaces console.log() and friends with level-based logging and filtering, with none of console's downsides.](http://pimterry.github.io/loglevel/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***EDIT 2***

Do use a library like [loglevel](http://pimterry.github.io/loglevel/)

See the answers below to understand how you can implement something like this by yourself.

**original answer:**

Do something like:

```
var myLogs = [];
(function () {
  var log = console.log;
  console.log = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    log.apply(this, args );
    myLogs.push(args);
  };
}());
```

The gloabl variable `myLogs` will contain your log data.

You may want to adopt the code to your needs. Maybe you want to make one string out of the args array.

**EDIT**

If you want to have `console.log`, `console.error`, `console.warn`, `console.info` and store the log level:

```
var logData = [];
(function () {
    var log = console.log,
        error = console.error,
        warn = console.warn,
        info = console.info;

    console.log = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        log.apply(this, args );
        logData.push({level: "log", arguments: args});
    };
    console.error = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        error.apply(this, args );
        logData.push({level: "error", arguments: args});
    };
    console.warn = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        warn.apply(this, args );
        logData.push({level: "warn", arguments: args});
    };
    console.info = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        info.apply(this, args );
        logData.push({level: "info", arguments: args});
    };
}());
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But how do i get error type like info,warning etc. In the arguments object im getting only error description.

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example of how also storing the log level. Be aware that now for every log you have an object with a property called `level`.

Comment: This does not catch all the javascript warnings and error messages which i see in the console but not getting saved in the global variable.I want to catch the Error and warning messages which get generated itself without me calling console.log or the other functions.

Comment: It should overwritte the console.log function and the others. So who ever calls this functions, the data should end up in the global array. Make sure that you run this piece of code first! And if somebody calls `throw new Error("error")` then this does not end up in this log. In your question you did only ask about how to collect data from calling `console.log`.

Comment: Question. If I overrite my console.<log level>  in this way, would I be able to capture also node modules, libraries logs? Sometime errors happens on the side of the library. It would be important to store them as well